# Exponential of an integrated matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

I am starting to read about Floquet theory and its basic setup

$\dot{x} = A(t) x$

where $A(t)$ is a $N$-dimensional $T$-periodic bounded square matrix for all $t$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

I was wondering why I do not (yet) see the solution

$x(t) = e^{\int_0^t A(s) ds} x(0)$

written anywhere. Here, I use the matrix exponential. Is there something wrong with this construction?

Comment: In general, $\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{X(t)}\right)\ne \frac{dX(t)}{dt}e^{X(t)}$

Comment: That is a solution if $A(t_1)$ commutes with $A(t_2)$ for every time $t_1,t_2$, but not in general. The general solution is given by the [Magnus expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion).